# Error while building App Inventor server

Tags: google-app-engine, server, app-inventor

I am trying to built my own App Inventor server.

I got the procedure form 'How to build App Inventor from MIT Sources' document. 
In that document, section in 2.3 Building App Inventor

when I run the command `ant MakeAuthKey` - Success
when I run the command `ant`, the error shows like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRnSA.jpg)
[image]

Here the version of software i have installed
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUFD5.jpg)
[image]

and appengine-java-sdk-1.9.27 is used

please help me to fix it.

Comment: Please don't post text as images. Instead copy-paste and format it accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: for questions about working with the App Inventor sources,please ask in the [Open Source Group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/app-inventor-open-source-dev/QVTy_r59GAY/-8fN2wshAgAJ)... tip: check the dependencies...